# No internet at startup of iOS application - Keep retrying

Tags: ios, reachability

I want to test at startup of the application , if the device is connected to the internet, if not display an alert notifying the user of the necessity to have the device connected to the internet, prevent him from starting the app if he is not connected, and at any time if he becomes disconnected, to reload the app, it's kind of like the principle of Clash of Clans…
At load test for internet, if no internet the app doesn't load..and at any time if the user looses connection, the app will restart. Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: You can use Reachability (https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) to check for internet connection.

Comment: As recommended by others you can use the Reachability code supplied by Apple, but you may get it rejected if you do it the way you are thinking. Apps shouldn't close or relaunch themselves this is because to the user it gives the impression it has crashed and Apple don't like that even if you warn them it is going to close, and in all honesty if an app did that to me I would instantly remove it. I do believe this is in the Apple Review guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [reachability](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) library . include it in the AppDelegate:

```
internetReachability = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"www.google.com"];
    // Internet is reachable
    internetReachability.reachableBlock = ^(Reachability*reach)
    {
        // Update the UI on the main thread
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"Internet Connection Established");
            // Update accordingly, use Storyboards or Navigation Stack
        });
    };

    // Internet is not reachable
    internetReachability.unreachableBlock = ^(Reachability*reach)
    {
        // Update the UI on the main thread
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // Update accordingly, use Storyboards or Navigation Stack

        });
    };

    [internetReachability startNotifier];
```

Answer (score 1):

To check the availability of connectivity [Reachability](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) class can be used. There is no API to exit the application [programmatically quit my iOS application](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1561/_index.html)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Reachability](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/index.html) to test for connectivity and have your app respond appropriately.

Answer (score -1):

You can set internet as a requirement in the plist. See this post: [My iPhone app needs a persistent network connection...how to specify UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338539/my-iphone-app-needs-a-persistent-network-connection-how-to-specify-uirequiredd)